# spacemacs and "file name too long" error on auto-save

Tags: spacemacs, auto-save

I reorganized some of the folders on my computer, in an attempt to get rid of old stuff and organize useful stuff. So with the new directory structure, I am getting all of these auto-save errors.

```
Error (auto-save): Auto-saving file1.org: Opening output file: File name too long, /home/xxx/.emacs.d/.cache/auto-save/site/#!....file1.org#
Error (auto-save): Auto-saving file2.org: Opening output file: File name too long, /home/xxx/.emacs.d/.cache/auto-save/site/#!....file2.org#
Error (auto-save): Auto-saving file3.org: Opening output file: File name too long, /home/xxx/.emacs.d/.cache/auto-save/site/#!....file3.org#
```

I am not sure of the cause of the errors. On thing I was thinking is that my hard drive is encrypted and this might interfere with the auto-save operation.

Is there a way to fix this, short of just moving the files to a different directory? Is there a setting I can change to increase the filename length? Has anyone else found a good workaround for this error.

UPDATE:

As per Stephen's suggestion, Spacemacs sets up the auto-save configuration in its own internal files. There is a single reference to auto-save location in the `.spacemacs` file. The variable `dotspacemacs-auto-save-file-location` specifies where a file is saved: the cache, in-place, or no auto-saving. Other than that, there did not appear to be any other configurable settings for auto-save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to show us the part of your `~/.emacs` which sets up the autosave machinery to use `home/xxx/.emacs.d/.cache/auto-save/site/...` (or is it a Spacemacs thing?).

But in any case, you should be able to shorten them as follows:

```
(advice-add 'make-auto-save-file-name :around
            #'my-shorten-auto-save-file-name)
(defun my-shorten-auto-save-file-name (&rest args)
  (let ((buffer-file-name
         (when buffer-file-name (sha1 buffer-file-name))))
    (apply args)))
```

Comment: Oh thanks so much for this. All the Emacs error messages just kept capturing the focus from whatever application I was working on :). Good point about the emacs config--this is a Spacemacs thing. Looks like there is only a reference to this in one of the Spacemacs setting variables `dotspacemacs-auto-save-file-location`. But the only choices are to either save the file in the cache, in-place, or not to auto-save. I can mention this in an edit to the question.